# Split array into equally weighted chunks based on order

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that gives me a cumulative percentage of some other number:

```
my_cumulative_array = np.asarray(range(0,50))/float(50)
```

I want to split this array into n groups **with equal weight** in each:

```
chunks    = [[row indexes 01-10], #First 20% based on order
            [row indexes 11-20],  #Second 20% based on order
            [row indexes 21-30],
            [row indexes 31-40],
            [row indexes 41-50]]
```

It seems like there should be a clever way to do this efficiently.

Comment: So, different chunks would have different number of elements, right?

Comment: Since your cumulative percentile values are increasing linearly, and since the size of the array is evenly divisible by 5, a trivial solution for the example you gave would be to just split `my_cumulative_percentile` into 5 equal chunks, e.g. `np.split(my_cumulative_percentile, 5)`, or to get the corresponding indices, `np.split(np.arange(my_cumulative_percentile.shape[0]), 5)`. Is that all you want, or is your real problem more complicated?

Comment: The chunks can be different sizes.  Sorry my example increased linearly but the first group might end up with 20 percent of elements (representing 10% of underlying variable weight) or 1 element (also representing 10% of underlying variable weight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question is not well defined, but looked fun. The following will split an array (`arr`) into a list of arrays (`chunks`) where the sum of each array in `chunks` is roughly equal.

```
splits = 5
arr = np.sin(np.random.rand(100)) + np.arange(100)/50.0
cum_arr = arr.cumsum() / arr.sum()
idx = np.searchsorted(cum_arr, np.linspace(0, 1, splits, endpoint=False)[1:])
chunks = np.split(arr, idx)
```

We can observe the split indices are not equally spaced:

```
print idx
[37 59 74 88]
```

while the sums of the blocks are:

```
print [np.sum(x) for x in chunks]
[27.93830, 29.51562, 28.30718, 29.23604, 28.7935]
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

From your sample output, it looks like you're looking for

```
chunks = [my_cumulative_array[i*(50/n):(i+1)*(50/n)] for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to the `numpy` boards on StackOverflow. In general python answers to numpy questions are discouraged due to performance issues. Especially when the user is looking for an efficient solution.

Comment: ah, thanks for the info! I'll keep that in mind going forwards