# Split "weighted" list/array into equal size chunks

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have a array of items with a weight assigned to each item. I want to split it into equal sized chunks of approx. equal cumulative weight. There is an answer here to do this using numpy https://stackoverflow.com/a/33555976/10690958
Is there a simple way to accomplish this using pure python ?

Example array:

```
[ ['bob',12],
 ['jack,6],
 ['jim',33],
....
]
```

or

```
a, 11
b,2
c, 5
d, 3
e, 3
f, 2
```

Here the correct output would be (assuming 2 chunks needed)

```
 [a,11],[b,2] - cumulative weight of 13
```

and

```
[c,5],[d,3],[e,3],[f,2] - cumulative weight of 13
```

To further clarify the question, imagine a situation of sorting a 100 people into 10 elevators, where we want each elevator to have the same approx. total weight (sum of weights of all people in that elevator). So then the first list would become names and weights. Its a load-balancing problem.

Comment: Could you share a larger example array? And expected output

Comment: my_list = ["a", "foo", "booo", "qooo", "moo", "doo", "goo"]
    chunks = [my_list[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(my_list), 2)]
would work it would put items into a new list paired - I am not sure though I understand your input data

Comment: edited it again to clarify. Hope the question is more clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to mimic `cumsum`: build a list summing the weights. At the end you get the total weight. Scan the list with the cumulated weight, and create a new chunk each time you reach total_weight/number_of_chunks. Code could be:

```
 def split(w_list, n_chunks):
    # mimic a cumsum
    s = [0,[]]
    for i in w_list:
        s[0]+= i[1]
        s[1].append(s[0])
    # now scan the lists populating the chunks
    index = 0
    splitted = []
    stop = 0
    chunk = 1
    stop = s[0] / n_chunks
    for i in range(len(w_list)):
        # print(stop, s[1][i])     # uncomment for traces
        if s[1][i] >= stop:        # reached a stop ?
            splitted.append(w_list[index:i+1])    # register a new chunk
            index = i+1
            chunk += 1
            if chunk == n_chunks:                 # ok we can stop
                break
            stop = s[0] * chunk / n_chunks        # next stop
    splitted.append(w_list[index:])               # do not forget last chunk
    return splitted
```

Answer (score 1):

You need something like  this split:

```
 array =[ ['bob',12],
 ['jack',6],
 ['jim',33],
  ['bob2',1],
 ['jack2',16],
 ['jim2',3],
  ['bob3',7],
 ['jack3',6],
 ['jim3',1],
 ]


array = sorted(array, key= lambda pair: pair[1],  )

summ = sum(pair[1] for pair in array )

chunks = 4

splmitt = summ // chunks

print(array)

print(summ)

print(splmitt)

def split(array, split):

    splarr = []
    tlist = []
    summ = 0

    for pair in array:
        summ += pair[1] 
        tlist.append(pair)     
        if summ > split:
            splarr.append(tlist)
            tlist = []
            summ = 0


if tlist:
    splarr.append(tlist)
return splarr

spl = split(array, splmitt)

import pprint 

pprint.pprint(spl)
```

Comment: thanks. Your answer is correct, except for some spelling errors.