# Get Indices To Split NumPy Array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a NumPy array:

```
x = np.array([3, 9, 2, 1, 5, 4, 7, 7, 8, 6])
```

If I sum up this array, I get `52`. What I need is a way to split it up starting from left to right into roughly `n` chunks where `n` is chosen by the user. Essentially, the splits occur in a greedy fashion. So, for some number of chunks `n`, the first `n - 1` chunks must each sum up to at least `52/n` and they must be consecutive indices taken from left to right.

So, if `n = 2` then the first chunk would consist of the first 7 elements:

```
chunk[0] = x[:7]  # [3, 9, 2, 1, 5, 4, 7], sum = 31
chunk[1] = x[7:]  # [7, 8, 6], sum = 21
```

Notice that the first chunk wouldn't consist of the first 6 elements only since the sum would be `24` which is less than `52/2 = 26`. Also, notice that the number of elements in each chunk is allowed to vary as long as the sum criteria is met. Finally, it is perfectly fine for the last chunk to not be close to `52/2 = 26` since the other chunk(s) may take more.

However, the output that I need is a two column array that contains the start index in the first column and the (exclusive) stop index in the second column:

```
[[0, 7],
 [7, 10]]
```

If `n = 4`, then the first 3 chunks need to each sum up to at least `52/4 = 13` and would look like this:

```
chunk[0] = x[:3]  # [3, 9, 2], sum = 14
chunk[1] = x[3:7]  # [1, 5, 4], sum = 17
chunk[2] = x[7:9]  # [7, 8], sum = 15
chunk[3] = x[9:]  # [6], sum = 6
```

And the output that I need would be:

```
[[0, 3],
 [3, 7],
 [7, 9],
 [9, 10]
```

So, one naive approach using for loops might be:

```
ranges = np.zeros((n_chunks, 2), np.int64)
ranges_idx = 0
range_start_idx = start

sum = 0
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    sum += x[i]
    if sum > x.sum() / n_chunks:
        ranges[ranges_idx, 0] = range_start_idx
        ranges[ranges_idx, 1] = min(
                i + 1, x.shape[0]
            )  # Exclusive stop index
        # Reset and Update
        range_start_idx = i + 1
        ranges_idx += 1
        sum = 0
# Handle final range outside of for loop
ranges[ranges_idx, 0] = range_start_idx
ranges[ranges_idx, 1] = x.shape[0]
if ranges_idx < n_chunks - 1:
    left[ranges_idx:] = x.shape[0]

return ranges
```

I am looking for a nicer vectorized solution.

Comment: Where is the coding attempt to solve this?  You've describe the algorithm -- first implementation attempt generally falls on the poster (i.e. you).

Comment: What happens if the list is exhausted before reaching N chunks?  For instance, N=6, x=[3, 3, 3, 11, 11, 11].  You get chunks of [3, 3, 3], [11], [11], [11], and then you have no list remaining for the final two chunks.

Comment: @Prune Oops, I forgot the most important part. I've updated the question with code. In the case of exhaustion, you can end immediately. But in the real case, the list will always be long enough to fill up all of the chunks.

Comment: Ok, now it's very different question. I'm not sure what you mean by 'vectorized' in this case. Maybe use `np.cumsum()`.

Comment: @rpoleski "Vectorized" as in NumPy vectorized functions that allows us to avoid explicit for-loops

Comment: Have you tried `np.cumsum()` and `np.searchsorted()`? You don't need to loop over all elements, but still there is for loop. It will be much faster for large datasets, if that's your goal.

Comment: Yes, `cumsum` is a good start.  However, that sum needs to be reset every time we reach array_sum/n ... not as straightforward as we might wish.

Comment: @Prune, no one just needs to keep 2 indexes of `cumsum`. See my answer below.

Comment: Yup; nicely done.

Comment: i did more digging and found a similar question/answer that was close to what I needed and was completely vectorized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found inspiration in a [similar question that was answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33555976/2955541):

```
def func(x, n):
    out = np.zeros((n, 2), np.int64)
    cum_arr = x.cumsum() / x.sum()
    idx = 1 + np.searchsorted(cum_arr, np.linspace(0, 1, n, endpoint=False)[1:])
    out[1:, 0] = idx  # Fill the first column with start indices
    out[:-1, 1] = idx  # Fill the second column with exclusive stop indices
    out[-1, 1] = x.shape[0]  # Handle the stop index for the final chunk
    return out
```

**Update**

To cover the pathological case, we need to be a little more precise and do something like:

```
def func(x, n, truncate=False):
    out = np.zeros((n_chunks, 2), np.int64)
    cum_arr = x.cumsum() / x.sum()
    idx = 1 + np.searchsorted(cum_arr, np.linspace(0, 1, n, endpoint=False)[1:])
    out[1:, 0] = idx  # Fill the first column with start indices
    out[:-1, 1] = idx  # Fill the second column with exclusive stop indices
    out[-1, 1] = x.shape[0]  # Handle the stop index for the final chunk

    # Handle pathological case
    diff_idx = np.diff(idx)
    if np.any(diff_idx == 0):
        row_truncation_idx = np.argmin(diff_idx) + 2
        out[row_truncation_idx:, 0] = x.shape[0]
        out[row_truncation_idx-1:, 1] = x.shape[0]
        if truncate:
            out = out[:row_truncation_idx]

    return out
```

Comment: Note that for pathological case pointed out by @Prune, this code returns 2 rows more than my code.

Comment: Fair point. I've updated my answer to, hopefully, cover the pathological case

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that doesn't iterate over all elements:

```py
def fun2(array, n):
    min_sum = np.sum(array) / n
    cumsum = np.cumsum(array)
    i = -1
    count = min_sum
    out = []
    while i < len(array)-1:
        j = np.searchsorted(cumsum, count) 
        out.append([i+1, j+1])
        i = j 
        if i < len(array):
            count = cumsum[i] + min_sum
    out[-1][1] -= 1
    return np.array(out)
```

For the two test cases it produces the results you expected. HTH